# Can't Enable Hyper-V Platform in Windows 10 (on Parallels) - Error 0x80073701

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, parallels, hypervisor

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise on Mac, using Parallels 13.3.2 for .NET development at work.

After installing Docker Desktop for Windows, I'm running into Error 0x80073701 when trying to enable Hyper-V, specifically Hyper-V Platform.

[image]

I've enabled nested virtualization in my Parallels configuration, which is why I'm able to select the option to enable Hyper-V Platform (this checkbox was greyed out before I did this).

[image]

Has anybody been able to enable Hyper-V properly on a Windows 10 VM using Parallels?

Comment: You're trying to run a hypervisor inside a VM? I'd suggest the question is unrelated to Docker, and 100% related to running Hyper-V in a VM under Parallels.

Comment: Yes, I need to enable hypervisor in order to use Docker on the Windows VM. Updated the tags for this post.

Comment: @jbisa - Please provide the relevant information from the `CBS.log`